# Making sure my XNA game has focus before handling mouse and keyboard events

Tags: focus, mouseevent, xna-4.0

I'm developing a game that is mixed with winforms (for the map editor).  The problem I am facing is that even if the main game window isn't in focus, it still receives mouse change events (such as clicking and moving the mouse).

Is there a way to make sure my application is in focus before continuing on to handle these events are is there some kind of built in method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the `Game.IsActive` property to check if you should deal with mouse and keyboard input.

Answer (score 2):

If you add a reference to `System.Windows.Forms` you can check if the XNA window is active like this:

```cs
if (System.Windows.Forms.Form.ActiveForm ==
    (System.Windows.Forms.Control.FromHandle(Window.Handle) as System.Windows.Forms.Form))
{
    // Active form is the XNA window.
}
```