# Turn off mouse interactivity when not on applicaiton

Tags: c#, xna, window, mouse, contains

Lets say I have my C# program running, there is a button on the screen that if I put my mouse over it, it will change the game to a new page. Now I put another window in front of the project, lets say Google Chrome, and I am searching the web and clicking things, as I do that the project that is running right now is interacting with the mouse still and can have the button pressed even if I can't see the button. How do I turn this interaction off?

Comment: Your title and question are hard to read and unclear.  You should rephrase them to be more understandable if you expect to get an answer.

Comment: @PatrickQuirk I have updated the question to hopefully help people understand the question, it was a tricky topic to name, sorry about the miss-communication.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550640/making-sure-my-xna-game-has-focus-before-handling-mouse-and-keyboard-events  Possible duplicate?

Comment: @cloyd800 I think that this is. I would like to know how exactly Game.IsActive is incorporated into the program. I tried using it in the main class, in the update method and is having an error. IsActive is not showing up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using IsActive in your implementation of the Game class (called Game1 by default), you can avoid receiving input while your game is not in focus.

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    base.Update(gameTime);

    if (!IsActive)
    {
        return;
    }

    // ... do regualr update.
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.game.isactive.aspx

---

Alternatively, if you already have some Game State Management system, you can override the OnDeactived method in Game. This function will get called when the game looses focus.

```
protected override void OnDeactivated(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    base.OnDeactivated(sender, args);

    // If we are in a state which it makes sense to pause the game, then do it now.
    if (GameObjectManager.pInstance.pCurUpdatePass == BehaviourDefinition.Passes.GAME_PLAY)
    {
        GameObjectManager.pInstance.pCurUpdatePass = BehaviourDefinition.Passes.GAME_PLAY_PAUSED;
    }
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.game.ondeactivated.aspx